# The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly in C# with WebClient

Tags: c#

I have an issue getting html code from playstation page with WebClient and C#:

```
using (WebClient webCl = new WebClient())
{
    var url = "https://www.playstation.com/en-us/games/nioh-ps4/";

    var homeHtml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(webCl.DownloadData(url));
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(homeHtml))
    {
        return ...;
    }
    return ...;
}
```

On the line: `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(webCl.DownloadData(url));`

I got error:

> The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly

Why ? What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: is URL accessible. try to ping from machine. In most of cases this happens when URL is not accessible from calling machine

Comment: The url is accessible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is that your firewall is not allowing your app through. Adjust your security settings to allow the app through and try again.

Another possibility is that the server is throttling your connection, if you are crawling or hitting it too fast. Verify your code by running against other servers (eg: google.com) with a very limited rate.

Other possibilities include that there is something else the server does not like. For example, you may need to add a user agent header:

```
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
```

Or you may need to play with cookies.

You can use Fiddler to compare differences between browser and app requests and adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is Due to URL access issue. It can occur due to multiple scenarios

1. HOST is not accessible from your machine.
2. Host is rejecting the request.
3. Firewall blocking the request

Try ping  www.playstation.com. you should get the response.